# one notification per message in empathy indicator

Tags: indicator, empathy, notification

In the latest version of empathy (3.8.6) on ubuntu 14.04 I get a notification for every message I get from a person, which ends up clogging the entire panel. It used to be the case that I would only get one per person. Is this a feature or a bug?

It should also be said that the notification doesn't go away unless you exit/kill empathy.

If it's a feature, can it be turned off?

[image]